# jQuery/Javascript event handler runs twice instead of once - transitionend

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions, jquery-events

I am exploring possibilities coming from transition in CSS 3 but met strange behavior with event listeners that catch transition end event. My code looks like this:

```
var box = document.getElementById('someDiv').addEventListener( 'transitionend', 
    function( event ) { event.preventDefault(); $('.it-text').toggleClass('it-animate'); console.log('the end') }, false );
```

Transition works fine but log shows running function from callback twice. I also see this is happening here:

[jsfiddle example](http://jsbin.com/ajuzew/1/edit?html,js,output)

Why is it running twice and how to prevent it? Does it have anything with bubbling?

EDIT:

Given underneath solution works only partially - I used jQuery and  "one" event handler but it still doesn't work as intended - I want to make infinite loop with transition with toggling class on DOM object. Unfortunately `.on` runs twice although called once and toggling goes to hell, and `.one` runs as expected only ones do it doesn't make any loop :(
Any ideas?

```
var box = document.getElementById('someDiv');
$(box).on('transitionend', function ( e ) { $(box).toggleClass('myclass'); console.log('end')})
```

Comment: one is of type `webkitTransitionEnd` and one is of type `transitionend` you can check `event.type` and ignore un-interesting ones.